# Keep app integrity when using asynchronous calls in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-room

I am trying to keep my app clean by using good design principles. I want to keep the view, the logic and the database layers separate.

On the app I am working on now, I have a main activity, a singleton, a logic class and a I use room for the database access. I would like the activity to tell the logic to fetch data from the database and then load it in the singleton. Once it is done I need the main activity to show the data loaded in the singleton.

Room use LiveData. How can I use LiveData and then somehow return a result to the logic layer then load it into the singleton and let the main activity now that it is ready?

More generally, how can I tell a caller, from the callee, that the data is ready when it is asynchronous? For example if the main activity calls a logic class in another thread to load data, how can the logic class then let the main activity know it is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Handler to update the main activity on the UI thread:

```
LogicClass.functionThatAccessesRoom() {

  //get data from Room
  //...

  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
      //update the UI/views here
    }
  };
  handler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();

}
```